# PosgreSQL - Ensuring that at least one row exists in Table B for each row in Table A

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

Currently we have a `products` table which is fairly straightforward, the relevant part of the structure is something like this:

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
title text NOT NULL,
description text NOT NULL,
[...]
```

We now need to support an arbitrary number of languages for the title and description of each product, and the default language can vary from product to product (some sites may be multilingual from page to page).

So far, nothing too difficult - add a `product_metadata` table something like this:

```
product_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES products(id),
language_code_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES language_codes(id),
title text NOT NULL,
description text NOT NULL,
[...]
CONSTRAINT product_metadata_pkey PRIMARY KEY (product_id, language_code_id)
```

It seems like the next logical step is to move the existing `title` and `description` data into the new table and remove those columns from `products`, but this means that new rows in `products` can be added without a title or description.

Using `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` in `product_metadata` (and replacing the existing composite primary key with a unique constraint) and adding a `default_metadata_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES product_metadata(id)` column to `products` would ensure at least one metadata row per product, but it creates a loop between the tables.

It looks like using a deferrable constraint would accommodate this as long as the insert queries were written to insert into both tables before committing, but creating a deliberate cycle and relying on this kind of behaviour seems... messy. Is there a neater way to achieve the same thing, or is this one of those cases where that really is the right way to go?

Comment: Maybe a view combining data from both tables, with a trigger on the view on write which performs validation like ensuring a title/description/language code has been supplied?

Comment: So `products` does have more columns than just those you've shown, which should not be localised, right?

Comment: @Bergi that's right; there's intrinsic information about the product (dimensions, image URLs, etc.) that applies globally as well as technical details for internal use that shouldn't be localised or duplicated.